# How to change color and size of a bar in JQuery Sparklines on click?

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the color and size of a bar in a bar-chart created using JQuery Sparklines. I can access the bars in the bar-chart but I am struggling with making changes (modify color/size) to the clicked bar.

The current code shows bars with different colors but it is set while creating the sparklines. Upon clicking a bar, it returns the offset and the value in a popup box. How can I change the color and size of the bar when it is clicked?

```
var values = [500, 400, 700, 900, 1200, 300, 550];
var dates = {};
var now = new Date();

var counter = 0;
for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var d = moment(now).subtract(1 * i, "day").format("MMM DD");
  dates[counter] = d;
  counter++;
}

$("#bargraph1").sparkline(values, {
   type: "bar",
   barWidth: 20,
   barSpacing: 3,
   height: 100,
   tooltipFormat: "<span style=\"color: {{color}}\">&#9679;</span> 
     {{offset:names}} ({{value}})",
        tooltipValueLookups: {
        names: {
            0: 'Squirrel',
            1: 'Kitty',
            2: 'Bird',
            3: 'Three',
            4: 'Four',
            5: 'Five',
            6: 'Six',
            7: 'Seven'
            // Add more here
        }},
   colorMap: ["green", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red"]
});


$('#bargraph1').bind('sparklineClick', function(ev) {
    var sparkline = ev.sparklines[0],
        region = sparkline.getCurrentRegionFields();
    alert("Clicked chart on x="+region[0].offset+" y="+region[0].value);
});
```

Comment: $('#bargraph1').sparkline.defaults.common.lineColor = 'red'; try this..

Comment: Thanks for responding but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try destroying and recreating it:

```
var values = [500, 400, 700, 900, 1200, 300, 550];
var sparklineOptions = {
    type: "bar",
    barWidth: 20,
    barSpacing: 3,
    .
    .
}

$('#bargraph1').sparkline(values, sparklineOptions)
setupClickEventHandler()

function setupClickEventHandler() {
    $('#bargraph1').on('sparklineClick', function(ev) {
        $('#bargraph1').destroy() //<-- destroy
        var options = sparklineOpts
        //make changes to options here
        $('#bargraph1').sparkline(values, options) //<-- recreate with new options
        setupOnClickEventHandler()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid this will not solve the problem because I would not want to recreate a new bar chart but change color or size of a specific bar in a bar chart upon clicking that specific bar in the bar chart. The above solution will just recreate a complete new bar chart with updated options.